# observableArray bound table does not update when inside a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a page with a button which, when clicked, opens a modal dialog box that allows a user to search for products and add selected search results to an order.

I've created what I thought would work ([jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YuV55/1/)), however the search results table, which is bound to an `observableArray`, does not update.

If I remove the `data-bind` attribute from the `<div id="myDialog"/>` then the search results table updates correctly.

Also, I could only get the jsfiddle sample to repeat the same behaviour by placing the JavaScript in the body (framework option *no wrap (body)*), even though the script is loaded during the [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback in the actual implementation.

Where am I going wrong?

(I've posted all my code [here](https://gist.github.com/2882533/5be81bd53cfadec4c7c283d0f8afab131b6635f3).)

**Update:**

It seems like the Knockout `foreach` binding fails to see the updates to the `observableArray`. I've created my own binding ([updated jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YuV55/2/)) template which almost does what I want, but is not very satisfactory.

How can I get the `foreach` binding to recognise when the collection has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your broken sample with a minor modification to call the `.dialog()` in a setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YuV55/5/.  The jQuery UI dialog functionality moves the element to the bottom of the page, so it can mess up the bindings as the initial pass of `ko.applyBindings` hits it for a second time.

Here is another sample that calls `ko.applyBindings` specific to a container element (without the setTimeout): http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YuV55/6/.  This means that `ko.applyBindings` won't hit the moved dialog the second time, as it will be outside of the container element.

Comment: Brilliant, the container element worked like a charm. This is much better than my alternative and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of testing, I don't think it is possible to use a `foreach` bound to an `observableArray` in a jQuery UI dialog that is bound to the viewmodel - other bindings, e.g. `text`, that are bound to `observable` seem to work fine.

This [broken sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YuV55/4/) uses a dialog bound to the viewmodel which I based on a sample found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SnPdE/) (I think).

This [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YuV55/3/) accomplishes what I want. The dialog, however, is not bound to the viewmodel, instead I wire up a click handler to a button to launch the dialog (taken from this [article](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/)).

This works well and I'm happy with the results.