# Knockout nested control bindings

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm hoping to use knockout in a fairly slap-dash way to bind up an object to elements in a jQuery UI dialog box. There's quite a bit going on but I've been held up early on by knockout complaining that a property that I've nested inside a with-control-binding is not defined.

```
<div class="feedback-container" data-bind="with: feedback">
[... Other Bindings Here...]
<div class="feedback-list" data-bind="foreach: list">
    <div class="item">
        [... List binding here ...]
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Dialog Box for editing/creation-->
<div style="display: none" data-bind="with: $root.feedback.editFeedback">
    <div id="dialog_add_feedback" data-bind="attr: { title: mode }">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="field" data-bind="if: $root.feedback.mode() == 'contact'">
                <label>Lot</label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: lot"/>
            </div>
            <div class="field" data-bind="if: $root.feedback.mode() == 'lot'">
                <label>Contact</label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: contact"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

I am applying bindings like this:

```
ko.applyBindings({ "feedback" : new Feedback("contact") });
```

With the Feedback constructor being defined thusly (I've removed a whole bunch of other bindings for simplicity's sake):

```
function Feedback(mode) {
    var self = this;

    self.list = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.mode = ko.observable(mode);
    self.editFeedback = ko.observable();
}
```

Knockout is choking on the attribute binding to title. How is this happening? editFeedback is empty, ko's with-control-binding should prevent descendant bindings from being bound at all.

Does this have something to do with the fact that I've got a with-binding inside another with-binding? Is that allowed?

```
Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: mode is not defined; Bindings value: attr: { title: mode }
```

Comment: Maybe you can demonstrate your issue based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FUccj/?  Are you call `.dialog` at all?  if you are, then my suspicion would be that you are hitting the same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917264/observablearray-bound-table-does-not-update-when-inside-a-jquery-ui-dialog/10957190#10957190 where the dialog is getting moved to the bottom and KO attempts to bind it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as presented here has no problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/XU9Eb/

Comment: You're right, sorry I found out later that the reason I was running into a lot of different problems with knockout was because I had an observable array containing observable objects which were also composed of observable arrays and objects. Much of the observable nesting was unnecessary and once removed I was able to get everything working.